# <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?> not working, but hard coded form name works fine

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$dsn = '';
$user = '';
$password = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>



<?php
require 'mysqli_connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])){

  $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO test_table(comment) VALUES(?);');
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  $sth->execute(Array($comment));
}
?>
```

the code below will refresh the page, but not post to my database (nor will `REQUEST_URI`). If I put the actual php form name in place of the `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>` it works fine. I have tried double quotes, single quotes, and everything in between. What's up with this not working?

```
<form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method = "post">
      <p>Comment</p>
      <textarea name= "comment" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit" id = "submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that deals with the database? Is that PHP code in the same page?

Comment: Would you like to see the php file that connects to the data base or the file that inserts into the database, or both? - separate files obviously you have gotten that if you read this comment lol.

Comment: If the insert-code is in a different file, using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` won't work. Because that will post to the *same* page as you're already on. But the insertion-snippet is most relevant.

Comment: Gotcha, in that case, is there any security benefit of including this? if so, since they are in a separate file, a substitute to this?

Comment: this being php self, sorry.

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your SQL. You need a space after the table name. Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to make sure that you are made aware of any errors happening with your database. If not, it will silently fail and continue with the rest of the script.

Comment: Setting the action like this is unnecessary as the default action of forms is to submit to the current page.

Comment: Is your file named correctly, you are using `mysqli`?

Comment: Will add that, my SQL was working fine even with the space not there.

Comment: I am using SQLi and yes my file is named correctly

Comment: `$sth->execute(Array($comment));` is incorrect for `mysqli`, as is `new PDO`.

Comment: Oh I see what your saying, no all syntax is PDO mysqli was an old file name when I was using sqli

Comment: new PDO came straight from php PDO documentation